# How to remove JSX element from array in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an array of sections in state which holds some list of JSX elements. I'm trying to delete a specific element which is JSX from array when clicked on button but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Section.js

```
class Section extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sections: []
    };

    addLectureHandler = () => {
        const secs = this.state.sections;
        secs.push(
            <LectureItem key={Math.random} removeLectureHandler={() => this.removeLectureHandler(<LectureItem />)} />
        );
        this.setState({ sections: secs });
    };

    removeLectureHandler = (item) => {
        console.log(item);
    };

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <h4 className={classes.sectionTitle}>
                    Section 1 - <AssignmentIcon /> Introduction
                </h4>
                <div className={classes.addButtonContainer}>
                    <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.addButton} onClick={this.addLectureHandler}>
                        Create Lecture
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.lectureContainer}>{this.state.sections}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Section);
```

LectureItem.js

```
class LectureItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, removeLectureHandler } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div className={classes.titleContainer}>
                    <TextField className={classes.textField} label="New Lecture Title" name="lecture" margin="normal" />
                    <Button className={classes.removeButton} onClick={removeLectureHandler}>
                        <ClearIcon />
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                    Add
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(LectureItem);
```

Comment: you will have to keep track of indexes of every item you are pushing and use that index to remove. `this.state.sections.splice(index, 1)` would do.

Comment: Yeah i know that but I don't know to keep track of indexes in this situation hence I'm not using .map

Comment: First of all:divide your data  in state and ui. In state you have to manage array of pure data for presentation and not ui items of it. By the array.map you can render items from the state.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Can you show me with example if you have time?

Comment: I dont think you should be storing your jsx elements in state in the first place. Take a look at some example todo apps like [this](https://codepen.io/marekdano/pen/bVNYpq). You can push an object in your state which may contain the info that your lectureItem is going to need as its props. And in your render you can just map over it.

Comment: I have made you a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sun-v4c6r) showing you a method to do it.

Comment: Reading the docs on https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html would be an ideal place to start.

Comment: Above sandbox shows it in both the class components as well as the functional way. If you're learning React I'd recommend to dive into functional components right away since class components are considered legacy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite straight forward, its more of a logic statement rather than react, Let me show it to you

For you method `addLectureHandler`
change push command to the following

```
 secs.push(
        <LectureItem key={Math.random} removeLectureHandler={() => this.removeLectureHandler(secs.length)} />
    );
```

You were passing `<LectureItem />` which is new element not the one you are pushing, so We will pass length (the actual new index of this element).

Next change you `removeLectureHandler` to this

```
removeLectureHandler = (indexToDelete) => {
    console.log(indexToDelete);
    const secs = this.state.sections;
    secs.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
    this.setState({ sections: secs });

};
```

And you have successfully deleted an element from the Sections and UI :-0